# Why is my Logistic Regression Model predicting the same thing repetitively?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/akshaydattatraykhare/diabetes-dataset

I used this kaggle dataset for my diabetes dataset and am trying to create a LogisticRegression model to predict outcomes.

I created the following class:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

class diabetesLogReg:
    df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aahan_bagga/Desktop/diabetes_data.csv")
    X=df.drop(["Outcome"], axis=1)
    Y=df["Outcome"]
    preg = 0
    glucose = 0
    BP = 0
    skinThickness = 0
    insulin = 0
    bmi = 0
    diabetesPedigreeFunction = 0
    age = 0
    def __init__(self, p, g, BP, ST, I, BMI, DPF, age):
        self.preg = p
        self.glucose = g
        self.BP = BP
        self.skinThickness = ST
        self.insulin = I
        self.bmi = BMI
        self.diabetesPedigreeFunction = DPF
        self.age = age

    def preprocessing(self):
        global Y_train
        global Y_test
        #K-fold cross validation
        kf = KFold(n_splits = 9, shuffle = True, random_state = 19)

        global X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test
        for training_index, testing_index in kf.split(self.X):
            X_train, X_test = self.X.iloc[training_index], self.X.iloc[testing_index]
            Y_train, Y_test = self.Y.iloc[training_index], self.Y.iloc[testing_index]


        #Noramlization marginally better than Standardization
        scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        global x_train_s, x_test_s
        x_train_s = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        x_test_s = scaler.transform(X_test)

    def train(self):
        global model
        model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 2000)
        model.fit(x_train_s,Y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(x_test_s)
        return f"{accuracy_score(Y_test, y_pred) * 100}%"
    
        # TUNE HYPERPARAMETERS HERE
    
    def diabetes_pred(self):
        prob = model.predict_proba([[self.preg, self.glucose, self.BP, self.skinThickness, self.insulin, self.bmi, self.diabetesPedigreeFunction, self.age]])
        print(prob)
        if prob[0,1] > 0.5:
            return "Diabetes"
        else:
            return "No Diabetes"
    
    #def decision_boundary_graph():
        #
    


d = diabetesLogReg(2,126,45,23,340,30,0.12,29)

d.preprocessing()
print(d.train())
print(d.diabetes_pred())
```

It is repetitively outputting:

```
80.0%
[[0. 1.]]
Diabetes
```

It has been outputting the "Diabetes" outcome for all the predictions it has made. I'm new to machine learning but I know that I haven't tuned my hyperparameters. Does it have to do with the length of the dataset, is it too short? Or maybe something to do with my k fold cross validation?

Answer (score 2):

I think it helps to start with a simple baseline. In your case there's additional complexity of wrapping the model in a class. Here's a simpler approach that is useful for checking things are working, and running some simple tests:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#Read in data
df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
features = df.drop(columns="Outcome")
y = df["Outcome"]

#Start off without CV to confirm basics, like model can learn
features_train, features_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#Preprocess the features
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(features_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(features_test)

#Fit default model
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

#Print scores
print('Accuracy scores')
train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(' Train:', accuracy_score(y_train, train_pred).round(3))
print(' Test: ', accuracy_score(y_test, test_pred).round(3))
```

We start off without using CV, just to ensure the model is fitting and we're getting reasonable results. The 0 predictions look good, but the 1 predictions are quite spread out. A histogram of the data identifies potential issues:

[image]

```
features_train.hist(bins=50, grid=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Some features have a value of 0. Whilst this makes sense for some features like Pregnancies, it's not a valid value for Age, BMI, and other measurements. There are ways to deal with this, including replacing those invalid zeros with the mean. Running `.hist()` on `y_train` shows that the dataset is imbalanced - using `class_weight="balanced"` will help `LogisticRegression` manage the imbalance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I don't think the issue is with the dataset, as it has a 10.0 usability rating on Kaggle. The only thing that stands out to me in your code is the 2000 iterations that you train the model for, it could be a bit too much and cause the model to overfit.

If you don't want to mess with hyperparameter tuning yet, try lowering the number of iterations yourself by different intervals, and see how the model behavior changes with different values of `max_iter`.

If you want to find the optimal number of iterations, try using `GridSearchCV` from sklearn ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)) on the `max_iter` hyperparameter in order to find the best number of iterations to train the model for.